# Completion of Banach space

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces

I want to prove that if $E'$ is a completion of a normed space $E$ then $E'$ is a Banach space. (with isometry $i$)

In my lecture the professor gave the following proof: 
First we can extend the $+$, $\cdot$ and $|| \cdot ||$ to $E'$ using that the diagrams commute (I'm only writing the one for the sum because it ilustrates the point of my doubt)

$E \times E \overset{i\times i}{\longrightarrow} i(E)\times i(E)$

$\space \space +$ $\downarrow$  $\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space\downarrow  +'$

$\space \space \space \space \space E \space \space \space \space \space \overset{i}{\longrightarrow} \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space E'$

Using that the diagram commutes it's simple to see that there is a unique extension of the $+$, $\cdot$ and $|| \cdot||$ to $+'$, $\cdot'$ and $||\cdot||'$ and then proving that $E'$ is normed is simple.

My doubt is why can we say that the diagram commutes, it would be true if the isometry $i$ is linear but I'm sure why we could say that.

Comment: How did your professor define $E'$?

Comment: Is any completion of $E$, $E'=cl(i(E))$

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you start the proof, no operator $+': i(E) \times i(E) \to E'$ is defined.

What is true is that there is a unique (uniformly continuous) operator $+': i(E) \times i(E) \to E'$ such that the diagram you've drawn commutes. I imagine that your professor intended you to take $+'$ to be that operator. Then, since $i(E) \times i(E)$ is dense in $E' \times E'$, we can uniquely extend $+'$ to a continuous operator $E' \times E' \to E'$.

Comment: To extend $+$ you need not only that $i(E) \times i(E)$ is dense (for uniqueness of the extension), but that $+$ is uniformly continuous on it (for existence of the extension).

Comment: The part that $+'$ is the only function that makes the diagram commute is clear and that I can extend it uniquely too. What bothers me is that if I define $+'$ with the diagram then $i$ is linear but I've read that isometries are not always linear.

Comment: @Johanna It is true that isometries need not be linear (though often in functional analysis when one talks of isometries linearity is understood from context). However, here you are defining a vector space structure on $E'$ and proving that it turns out that the sensible way to do this will make $i$ linear. Instead of being a problem, that is a good thing because it tells you the natural embedding of $E$ into its completion respects the vector space structure.

Comment: @GEdgar sure, but it is clear everything involved here is uniformly continuous since the individual maps in the diagram are so this makes no difference. The last line was more of an offhand comment since OP says they are fine with existence but I've now made a small edit to reflect that uniform continuity is important for this.